# pandas .groupby() creates a dataframe that has two header in different rows

Tags: python, pandas

[image: pandas dataframe]

The `df.groupby(['days'].sum()` does what I want, but moves "days" down to a row and when trying to plot the x-axis using days it says no labels found "days".

How would I have all my header on one row?
Is there another pandas feature that would do what I want?

I use this feature multiples times.

Comment: use `reset_index()` function after `df.groupby(['days'].sum()`, and then "days" column is not your index and will be a column in your data frame

Answer (score 2):

`as_index=False` is what you're looking for:

```
df.groupby(['days'], as_index=False).sum()
```

This parameter prevents transferring `days` to index. Instead it will create a regular column, which you can use as usual.